# Error recieved: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

Hello so i keep getting this error:

```
Error recieved: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)"
```

My project works fine when i programmed using xcode 8 and swift 3. But now i downgraded to use xcode 7.3.1 and swift 2.3 and i get this error.

Below is my appdelegate file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let viewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let navController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        self.window?.rootViewController = navController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        //facebook
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        //Google
        var error: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&error)
        assert(error == nil, "Error Configuring google services \(error)")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }

 func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return  FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

        if error != nil {
            print ("Error sigining in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
```

SignInController.swift file:

```
class SignInController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
    //starts here
    let fbButton:FBSDKLoginButton = {
        let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
        button.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Sign In"
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil {
            print("I got token: \(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()?.tokenString)")
            view.addSubview(fbButton)
            fbButton.center = view.center
            fbButton.delegate = self
            self.fetchprofile()
        }

        else {
            print("Dont have token")
            self.view.addSubview(fbButton)
            fbButton.center = self.view.center
            fbButton.delegate = self
            }

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        let googleButton = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 150, width: 100, height: 50))
        view.addSubview(googleButton)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print("I'm in")
        fetchprofile()
    }

    func fetchprofile() {

        print("Getting profile")
        print("FB version: \(FBSDKSettings.sdkVersion())")
        print("Tokensssss:  \(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()?.tokenString)")

        let parameters = ["fields": "email"]

        let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters, HTTPMethod: "GET")

        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error recieved: \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let email = result["email"] as? String else {
                return
            }

            print("Email: \(email)")
        }
    }

    func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("Logged out")
    }




    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

Error receiving:

```
Error recieved: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            "fbtrace_id" = CgykKyskOcd;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}}
```

Please could someone assist. Thanks

Here is my info-plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb{{myFB-Id}}</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.99471515633-84bp5qjrl8jqf0drm10aucsrrepgta12</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>{{Bundler-id}}</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>{{myFB-id}}</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>{{myFB-displayName}}</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you add keychain for this ?  because for facebook login you must add keychain If not then add

Comment: If you want demo I can lead you with complete facebook login

Comment: @Jecky what do you mean keychain? Yes please could you show me a demo

Comment: Sorry, I think You are working in swift 3.0 and according to swift 3.0 I commented on your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** your .**plist** file https://gist.github.com/himanshu-benzatine/1ad78c7d17051c36f60b934b64725f31

**// put this code in your button click method**

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        return
}

let login:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

login.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ], handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        }else if(result.isCancelled){
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        }else{
            //Handle login success
            self.returnUserData()
        }
    })




func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User Logged Out")

}

func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, friends, birthday, cover, devices, picture.type(large)"])

    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    if ((error) != nil)
    {
          // Process error
          print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    else
    {
          print(result)

    }
   })
}
```

// **Add this code in your AppDelegate.swift file**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}



func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication:  sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/himanshu-benzatine/1ad78c7d17051c36f60b934b64725f31 Update Your .plist file as follow

Comment: i posted my info-plist and double checked but still having the same error

Comment: @user3497437 what kind of error occur tell me ? and are you using swift version 2 or 3.0 ?

Comment: i'm using swift version 2. My error is posted on the question page. "Error receving". I have also added what you mentioned in appdelegate file prior to you mentioning it to no success. When i used swift 3 it works but had to downgrade to swift 2 and now having this error

Comment: @user3497437 i m also using swift 2.0 and this my code is working perfectly in swift 2.0

Comment: yea i don't know  why i keep getting the error. When i run it on swift 3 it works but not on swift 2 it gives me the error as mentioned above. I'm confused as to why

Comment: let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, friends, birthday, cover, devices, picture.type(large)"])
 replce your this line and check it @user3497437

Comment: tried it and still returns the error. Its my info-plist file ok?

Comment: I will not check your whole info.plist file you just compare your file with my info.plist file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126080/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-user3497437).

Comment: uploading the zipfile

Comment: @user3497437 give up vote if your problem solve with my solution . thank you