# iOS: Facebook Access Token is Nil

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-access-token

Why is the Facebook access token in viewdidload nil even after test user is logged in?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
        // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
        let vc = MainViewController()
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is Facebook login manager code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40082252/6656894 check this answer your problem will be solve.

Comment: This could be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950937/fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-nil-after-quitting-app/32963964#32963964