# swift facebookSDK retrieve a user's intro?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've built a Facebook login button.
I was able to get the user's information including name, email, gender, id, *etc.*  I basically just insert the parameters after "fields":

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
```

However, I got stuck trying to retrieve the user's "intro", (under the user's profile):

[image: click here to see a sample]

I looked up the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-user_events
seems to me none of them is able to get the "intro" of the user.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40082252/6656894 refer this answer for retrive data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to request `user_about_me` [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions), then the "intro" field you're looking for is under the field labeled `about`.